# Can a child class override a parent's property changing its type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, interface, c#-9.0

I'm using Unity, but I think It's not relevant.

I have a base abstract class representing a controller `CharacterMovementController` and 3 child classes, each one for each axis. I need those 3 to have a "Preset" that can be used by that class. Now I’m defining the possibility or not of using some kind of preset by implementing the `IStatePreset<T> where T : CharacterMovementController` interface in the preset class, for example, if I want the `PresetA`  to be used only in X and Z axis I would do this:

```
public class PresetA : ScriptableObject, IStatePreset<CharacterXMovementController>, IStatePreset<CharacterZMovementController> {}
```

I need the `CharacterMovementController` to have a property of type `IStatePreset` without the need to specify the type of `T`  so that I could then constrain it in the child classes. Like this:

```
public abstract class CharacterMovementController : MonoBehaviour
{   
...
    public abstract IStatePreset Preset{ get; protected set; }
...
}

public class CharacterXMovementController : CharacterMovementController
{   
...
    public abstract IStatePreset<CharacterXMovementController> Preset{ get; protected set; }
...
}

public class CharacterZMovementController : CharacterMovementController
{   
...
    public abstract IStatePreset<CharacterZMovementController> Preset{ get; protected set; }
...
}

public class CharacterYMovementController : CharacterMovementController
{   
...
    public abstract IStatePreset<CharacterYMovementController> Preset{ get; protected set; }
...
}
```

But this isn't possible. Any workarounds?

Comment: Sounds like `CharacterMovementController` should be generic as well so that you can forward the type

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the `CharacterMovementController` generic?

```
public abstract class CharacterMovementController<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : CharacterMovementController<T>
{   
...
    public IStatePreset<T> Preset{ get; protected set; }
...
}
```

Then inherit the controller in the children classes and specify the generic type. No need to override or shadow the Preset property in the child classes.

```
public class CharacterXMovementController : CharacterMovementController<CharacterXMovementController>
{   
...
...
}
```

As mentioned by @derHugo "you can / should also again limit the the `T` to `where T CharacterMovementController<T>`"

Comment: you can / should also again limit the the `T` to `where T CharacterMovementController<T>`

Comment: Doesn't that create a recursive reference? I think limiting the `T` to `MonoBehaviour`?

Comment: For type constraints that's totally fine - either way you are already passing in `CharacterXMovementController` as `T` ;) It just is required if the `IStatePreset` is also type constrained to `public interface IStatePreset<T> where T : CharacterMovementController<T>`